# Merge branch to a different branch from the starting branch

Tags: git

I have branch master and branch dev. I started a feature branch from master by mistake. Meaning, I did `git checkout -b feature-branch` while I was on master.

Now I want to merge the feature branch on branch dev. How do I do it?

Comment: `git checkout master && git merge featurebranch` ??

Comment: @ckruczek but i want to merge into dev

Comment: Then checkout dev instead of master. Whats the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are not too many commits, then "git cherrypick" is an option:

1. create new topic branch from dev branch
2. use git cherrypick to copy commits from the original topic branch
3. delete the original topic branch

EDIT: I added an example how to do the same with "git rebase" command:

1. figure out the hash for the commit that is the parent of the topic branch
2. git rebase --onto dev hash_b4_topic topicbranch

You can also use the branch~N syntax instead of the commit hash if you are not afraid of counting commits ;) Although it just one command, I would still use the first option, because it it takes quite a bit more effort to get it right (i.e. check the manual, select the right command line arguments). So it would make sense only for moving longer topic branches.

Comment: this actually is the easiest solution!

Comment: Another nice option would be "git rebase", but that would probably take more time and effort to get the command line arguments right.

Comment: just out of curiousity, how do i do this with rebase?

Comment: Sure, I also included the rebase option.

Answer (score 0):

to merge the commited changes that you've made from one `branch` to another you could use: `git merge <branchname>`. Let me set you an example:"

I want to merge the changes i've made on branch `dev` with my `master branch`. The first thing i'll do is commit the changes on branch `dev` then i'll switch to branch `master` and i will merge the changes from the `dev` branch by using:

```
git merge dev
```

So step by step: first commit your changes from the development branch.

```
git commit -m "<commit message>"
```

Step two: Switch to the master branch

```
git checkout master
```

Last step: merge your changes from the `dev` branch/

```
git merge dev
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'git log' to find the point before you started your work and then use 'git diff' to find the difference between the current HEAD and that point. 'git apply' will apply that diff.

1. On your feature branch, use git log to find the start of your work. Record the commit before your work.

   ```
    git checkout feature-branch
    git log
   ```
2. Store the difference between the point you found above and your work (the current HEAD revision). HEAD is an implied argument.

   ```
    git diff (commit_from_step_above) > patch.txt
   ```
3. Apply your change to a correct feature branch.

   ```
    git checkout dev
    git checkout -b proper_feature-branch
    git apply patch.txt
    (add, commit, etc)
   ```

If others have changed the same files you're changing, you'll have a merge conflict. This is expected.